# PHP: Wordpress widget doesn't return address of client by their IP Address

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, ip

I want to get the client's exact address by getting their IP address, and the code I am currently using in PHP:

```
        $ip  = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=myAPIKey&ip=$ip";      
        $d = file_get_contents($url);        
        $data = explode(';' , $d);
        $lat = $data['8'];
        $long = $data['9'];
        $city =  $data['6'];
        $state =  $data['5'];
        $country =  $data['4'];
        $address = "$city, $state $country";
```

Whenever I go onto the website, the location is displayed as: Denpasar, Bali Indonesia (which is where I currently am), but when I get friends to get the website (or I use a VPN) it also says: Denpasar, Bali Indonesia.

My only guess is that when they run the page, the widget isn't rerunning the code and just displays my results.
If so - how can I fix that?

And if that isn't correct - what is the problem?

Comment: Definitely could be a caching issue, but there's not enough information here to know where the caching would be taking place.  It could be happening within the WordPress theme or plugin code, or with an edge cache like varnish.  Does this happen both when logged in and logged out?

Comment: As Linnea says it is likely due to caching (a "snapshot" of your page is taken on first visit & this snapshot served to subsequent visitors whatever their IP). If so, additional info is needed: caching plugin used  e.g. WP Supercache, W3TC. Whether GeoIP required on all or just selected pages, by shortcodes, or within a widget.

Comment: The caching plugin used is: W3TC.
And yes, it happens both logged in and logged out.